# epoll server won't unbind

Tags: linux, epoll

I have written an epoll server over Ubuntu Linux kernel 3.5.0-23, working very well with one problem:
if a client connects, and then logs off, I can restart the server immediately.
However, if the client is still connected and I close the server, he will be disconnected, but the port will still be bound for X seconds (can't tell the X, I'll say it about 20).
This will also happen if I'm terminating the program with the compiler.

When closing, I'm using the exact same function I'm using when the client leaves:

```
int CEpollClient::Close ()
{
    if(m_socket!=SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
    int res=::epoll_ctl (m_server_handler, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, m_socket, 0);
    _debug_message("client exits");
    _debug_message(res);
    shutdown(m_socket,SHUT_RDWR);
    ::close (m_socket);
    m_socket=SOCKET_ERROR;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

This is a part of the client class, so this exact same code is called whether I'm closing the client after he left or initialize this myself.
I'm also closing the listening socket when closing the server:

```
if (m_listener != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    _debug_message("stop listener");
    code=epoll_ctl(m_epoll_handler,EPOLL_CTL_DEL,m_listener,0);
    _debug_message(code);
    shutdown(m_listener,SHUT_RDWR);
    ::close(m_listener);
    m_listener = SOCKET_ERROR;
}
```

Can someone offer any idea? This is not terrible and it is workable, but it does looks like a bug.
The return code in the debug message s is always 0 - no errors.
So why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you cannot re-use the socket as you need to request it to the system. Before the call to bind(2) do something like this:

https://github.com/edsiper/monkey/blob/master/src/mk_socket.c#L114

i hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry...  I'm not reusing the socket. As I have written, I can terminate the program, and re-run it and still get this bind error. TY for the time

Answer (score 1):

You question not epoll related, but socket related. The reason why you cannot reuse that socket is that it's still lingering in TCP `TIME_WAIT` state. That is normal behavior, by design. The delay is usually twice the maximum segment lifetime to ensure that a full roundtrip to perform a correct shutdown is possible in any case, but it is also configurable with `SO_LINGER`. You may be tempted to simply configure `SO_LINGER` to something much shorter, but don't do that. Playing with this dial is *not advisable* as it may interfere with a normal, graceful shutdown.

Another option is to set the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option, which is probably what you want. Note that `SO_REUSEADDR` tells the socket layer to forget about the correctness promises it makes and deliberately break normal operability. Basically you're telling your networking library: *"Yes I know it's wrong to do this, but I promise that nobody cares about that socket any more and no evil things will happen"*.
Which is exactly what's the case in your example. You have already closed the socket the hard way, it's gone and nobody else is using it, and all you care about is using it anew as soon as you can.

For a description of the available socket options see [`socket(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket), for example.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: k.o.'s answer is nevertheless spot-on with all relevant information (though not optimally explained). I'll see if I can edit to make it a bit clearer.